# MongoDB TTL index never deletes records

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ttl, database-indexes, mongodb-indexes

I created an index as shown below and added a createdAt field to each new record added to the db. The records should be auto-deleted after 24 hours however I have waited days and nothing has been deleted.

```
db_connect.collection("records").createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
```

Adding record to the database

```
// Add info to db to search
    console.log("Adding info to database..");
    const otherAddress = e.target.address.value;
    const newRecord = {
        holderAddress: this.props.account,
        otherAddress: otherAddress,
        date: new Date(),
        data: encryptedData
    }
    await fetch("http://localhost:420/record/add", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(newRecord),
    }).catch(error => {
        window.alert(error);
    });
```

Endpoint it calls:

```
recordRoutes.route("/record/add").post(function (req, response) {
let db_connect = dbo.getDb();
let myobj = {
    holderAddress: req.body.holderAddress,
    otherAddress: req.body.otherAddress,
    data: req.body.data,
    createdAt: req.body.date
};
db_connect.collection("records").insertOne(myobj, function (err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    response.json(res);
});
```

Below is a screenshot from MongoDB website confirming there is an index..

[image]

Output from: db_connect.collection("records").stats().then(r => { console.log(r)});

```
 createdAt_1: {
  metadata: [Object],
  creationString: 'access_pattern_hint=none,allocation_size=4KB,app_metadata=(formatVersion=8),assert=(commit_timestamp=none,durable_timestamp=none,read_timestamp=none,write_timestamp=off),block_allocation=best,block_compressor=,cache_resident=false,checksum=on,colgroups=,collator=,columns=,dictionary=0,encryption=(keyid=,name=),exclusive=false,extractor=,format=btree,huffman_key=,huffman_value=,ignore_in_memory_cache_size=false,immutable=false,import=(enabled=false,file_metadata=,repair=false),internal_item_max=0,internal_key_max=0,internal_key_truncate=true,internal_page_max=16k,key_format=u,key_gap=10,leaf_item_max=0,leaf_key_max=0,leaf_page_max=16k,leaf_value_max=0,log=(enabled=false),lsm=(auto_throttle=true,bloom=true,bloom_bit_count=16,bloom_config=,bloom_hash_count=8,bloom_oldest=false,chunk_count_limit=0,chunk_max=5GB,chunk_size=10MB,merge_custom=(prefix=,start_generation=0,suffix=),merge_max=15,merge_min=0),memory_page_image_max=0,memory_page_max=5MB,os_cache_dirty_max=0,os_cache_max=0,prefix_compression=true,prefix_compression_min=4,readonly=false,source=,split_deepen_min_child=0,split_deepen_per_child=0,split_pct=90,tiered_object=false,tiered_storage=(auth_token=,bucket=,bucket_prefix=,cache_directory=,local_retention=300,name=,object_target_size=10M),type=file,value_format=u,verbose=[],write_timestamp_usage=none',
  type: 'file',
  uri: 'statistics:table:index-3854-9052224765860348301',
  LSM: [Object],
  'block-manager': [Object],
  btree: [Object],
  cache: [Object],
  cache_walk: [Object],
  'checkpoint-cleanup': [Object],
  compression: [Object],
  cursor: [Object],
  reconciliation: [Object],
  session: [Object],
  transaction: [Object]
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you view the index parameters from the GUI?  Is `ttl` there?

Comment: I cant see anything more about the index via the GUI, however I have updated the question with the info I have :)

Comment: What does `db.records.getIndexes()` show?

Comment: ... and this too. `db.getCollectionInfos( { name: "records" } )`.  Is this a time series or a capped collection?

Comment: [
  {
    name: 'records',
    type: 'collection',
    options: {},
    info: {
      readOnly: false,
      uuid: UUID("9c90e662-bb88-4e6a-9a4c-8556abfa1a48")
    },
    idIndex: { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: '_id_' }
  }
]

Comment: [
  { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: '_id_' },
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { createdAt: 1 },
    name: 'createdAt_1',
    expireAfterSeconds: 120
  }
]

Comment: No it is not a capped collection

Comment: Seems the docs should expire after 2 minutes.  :-/  Are the `createdAt` values in the documents what you expect?  I.e., they're not set into the future somehow or not a real Date Object?

Comment: Sadly not :/ this is an example entry: createdAt: "2022-03-09T17:13:11.497Z"
data: "33586b52b46c60887906f1b9c6eded6a4f34b78c3f7105f3d8846bf6039ec2e12ayIk9K0+OXJhB5SHDeqAgJ3WYPr9bExsxB7h16CT3akrc8zMHALz2+Gk1A==d1298595cbec55cf911e3ed77f45b7e8ac684f87dfa0e5d43a71952ad646dbeb"
expireAfterSeconds: 120
holderAddress: "0x647DD1F1Ae4F2127A9b9FBb513e39b22a8551Db5"
otherAddress: "0x647DD1F1Ae4F2127A9b9FBb513e39b22a8551Db5"
_id: "6228e027a10f84480e1191d6"

Comment: Your `createdAt` isn't a string, is it?  When I look at my dates in `mongosh` they look like `createdAt: ISODate("2022-03-11T20:04:42.098Z")`.

Comment: Hmm it looks like they could be as when I send my HTTP req to add to the db, the body containing the parameters including createdAt is JSON.stringify 'ed

Comment: This has fixed my issue, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expiration of data requires that the indexed field value be a BSON date, or an array of BSON dates.

[MongoDB Reference Manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/#behavior)

```
Expiration of Data
TTL indexes expire documents after the specified number of seconds
has passed since the indexed field value; i.e. the expiration threshold
is the indexed field value plus the specified number of seconds.

If the field is an array, and there are multiple date values in the index,
MongoDB uses lowest (i.e. earliest) date value in the array to calculate
the expiration threshold.

If the indexed field in a document is not a date or an array that holds
one or more date values, the document will not expire.

If a document does not contain the indexed field, the document will not
expire.
```